# WordPress Rewrite regex: what does the trailing ? mean?

Tags: regex, wordpress, url-rewriting

In WordPress rewriting, I often see examples like this:

```
$wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%issue_project%', '(.+?/)?', 'issue_project=');
```

It has a `?` mark at the end of the regular expression.  Some don't.  What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

It means a lazy rather than a greedy regular expression.  See here.

[What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

`.+`  means one or more characters -- any characters

`.+/` means one or more characters ending with the very last `/` found. So given `abc/def/gh/` the `.+` matches `abc/def/gh`.

`.+?/` means one or more characters matching the shortest sequence, not the longest. So given `abc/def/gh/` the `.+` matches `abc`.

The `(whatever)?`  trailing `?` after the parenthetical expression makes that expression optional.  `(whatever)?` means the same thing as `(whatever){0,1}`, that is, it accepts zero or one repetitions of `(whatever)`.

Comment: but what does `(.+?/)?` means?